# Out-of-source builds in temporary directory with Teamcity

Tags: teamcity

I'm using Teamcity to build a CMake project. I'd like to leave `Clean all files in the checkout directory before the build` off, so that it doesn't have to keep re-fetching all the source for minor changes. Is there a way I can specify the CMake working directory to be in some temporary directory that Teamcity will create for me, and then delete when the build is done?

I thought `%system.teamcity.build.tempDir%` might do it but there doesn't seem to be any documentation for it, and I think that might just be the directory where all builds go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%system.teamcity.build.tempDir%` is fine. And so is `%TEMP%` actually (on Windows, or `%env.TEMP%` in TeamCity-speak): the agent overrides the env var and uses a clean temp directory for every run.